# Twitter feed not working

Tags: php, twitter, rss

Hi I use the following PHP code to parse a twitter feed and display the latest two tweets in the footer of a website..

```
<ul id="twitter_update_list" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/fixedgearfrenzy.rss');
    $arrFeeds = array();

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) 
    {           
        if($count < 2)
            echo('<li><span style="word-wrap:break-word;">'.substr($node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue, 17).' </span><a href="'.$node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue.'">'.substr($node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue, 0, 16).'</a></li>');

        $count = $count + 1;
    }
?></ul>
```

For some reason it seems to not always work and most of the time the following error is displayed..

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/fixedgearfrenzy.rss) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /home/fixedge1/public_html/catalog/view/theme/CartMania-Clean/template/common/footer.tpl on line 336Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/fixedgearfrenzy.rss" in /home/fixedge1/public_html/catalog/view/theme/CartMania-Clean/template/common/footer.tpl on line 336
```

I can't work out why on earth it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, any ideas??

The website is http://www.fixedgearfrenzy.co.uk and it's the twitter feed in the bottom right

Comment: You should update your URL to the [currently supported API endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline): `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=fixedgearfrenzy`

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Twitter impose a per-hour limit on the number of times you can load a feed.  If your results are intermittent, this is probably the reason why.  Try caching the feed results locally to avoid re-loading the same data from Twatter over and over again.

Comment: sounds reasonable, any advice on how to achieve this??  Sorry I'm just quite new to php

Comment: Basically, you'll want to change the above code to read from a string instead of a file, then write a function that uses `filemtime()` and `file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/statuses...')` to only load the data from Twitter when `time() - filemtime() > (5*60)`.  The `filemtime()` functions returns a unix timestamp for the input file.  HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You should [use a valid `user-agent` when using `DOMDocument` to load a remote resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php#91384).

```
<?php

// Set a valid user-agent
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/fixedgearfrenzy.rss');
$arrFeeds = array();

// rest of your code...
```